# How to write an Excel function to count the number of unique records in a specific range of cells

Tags: excel, function, vba

I have two columns, one with customer ID numbers and the other with count of plans. Customer ID has letters and numbers in it while count of plans is a nonzero integer.

I need a function that first: specifies a range of customer IDs that correspond with a specific plan count (ex. all customer IDs which have a corresponding plan count of 4)

and then second: counts the number of unique customer IDs for that plan count.

So for example for these IDs with count of plans all equal to 4:

```
06U0547
06U0547
06U0547
06U5166
06U5166
06U5166
06U4990
06U4990
06U4990
06U4777
06U4777
```

with matching column

```
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
```

I want Excel to say "ok, let's only look at these 9 customer IDs with count of plans equal to 4, and then count the unique numbers. Which would be 3 unique numbers." So the function should return "3". This should work for any n, so for n=5 the function should return "1", because there is only 1 unique customer ID for the plan count of 5.

How should I write this? I looked up unique value functions on here but none of them work for me, and I can't find any function on selecting the range. I'm just an intern I don't know much if anything about VBA.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Your problem statement is a bit unclear. You stated there are two columns, but you're only showing one. Who/How is selecting the range of the customer IDs? Are you wanting the function to count the number of repeats for a single ID? Is the second column a part of what the function looks at?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me clear it up. The matching column to the one I showed is all 4's. Each of these customer IDs has 4 plans in force. I want to the function to tell me that the number of unique customer ID's which have 4 plans is equal to 3. (06U0547, 06U5166 & 06U4990 are the only unique values in the IDs column, and there are 3 of them). So I want the function to say "for some n # of count of plans in force, look at IDs in ID column with that number of plans in force. For n=4 plans in force there are 9 ID matches, but only 3 of them are unique IDs, so return 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this vba code which uses a `worksheet_change` event,

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Address = "$C$1" And Range("C1").Value <> "" And IsNumeric(Range("C1").Value) Then
    Range("D1:E20").ClearContents
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    k = 1
    i = Range("C1").Value
    For j = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("B" & j).Value = i Then
            Range("D" & k).Value = Range("A" & j).Value2
            Range("E" & k).Value = Range("B" & j).Value2
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next j
    Range("D1:E" & j).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
    Range("F1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(4))
End If
End Sub
```

If your data is in columns A and B, enter 4 or 5 in the cell `C1`. The macro detects changes to the cell `C1` and removes the duplicates of the data range in columns D and E. It then tell you the unique counts in Cell `F1`.

[image]

[image]